# Why Redis Cluster's shards get 0 Key

Tags: redis, nosql, sharding, redis-cluster

We have a Redis cluster consisting of 8 nodes that are working on the ubuntu 20.04 server. Every single node has 6 instances of Redis servers working on different ports. We have 48 Redis instances working on 8 nodes and there are 16 shards with 1 master and 2 slaves each.

Almost since the beginning, we have had these 3 shards that have 0 keys or fewer keys than the rest of the shards. We change the master of the shard -not with replica- when we detect a 0 key shard. After this shard starts getting some key but not as much as the rest of the shards.

On average rest of the shards have 31-32K keys however these 3 shards have 10, 200 or 500 keys stored on them after we change master of the shards.

The big problem is start when running a query with these shards. The error is "NOREPLICAS Not enough good replicas to write".

Could you please help?

Comment: There are quite a lot of details missing, the network, the configuration, the logs, etc., so actually it's impossible to give you a concrete answer, but perhaps this paragraph is helping: https://redis.io/docs/manual/scaling/#resharding-the-cluster

Comment: Furthermore you might better get an answer on https://serverfault.com, perhaps also have a look at https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic